# Way to check where the MySQL connection was initialized?

Tags: mysql, connections

Is there a way to identify who created the MySQL connection?

For example:
in file a.php
`$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, null, $port, $socket);`
I would like to know that this connection was initialized from a.php

I switched on the logger but all it told me that the connection was made but not who initialized it.
`Connect    root@localhost on  using Socket`

Comment: Who has the root password?

Answer (score 0):

Who has the root password?  If there are multiple admins with root permissions, change them to non "root" user names, but with `ALL PRIVILEGES`.  Then you can distinguish them in the general log.

"Socket" implies the same machine; nothing provides what program.

I recommend you add comments to every query, perhaps with the filename and line number (`__LINE__`).

Comment: I would like to know which file or from where the connection was made? Not which user made the connection. Like in the above example, I would like to know that a.php created the connection.

Comment: @AnirudhSridhar - I added to my Answer.